# What were the "pieces" of Moses' transmission of the Oral Law?

Tags: halacha-theory, moshe-rabbeinu, mishna, maseches-eruvin

[BT Eruvin 54b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Eruvin.54b.11?lang=bi&with=Chidushei%20Agadot&lang2=en) presents the method of Moses' Torah study:

> תנו רבנן: כיצד סדר משנה? משה למד מפי הגבורה. נכנס אהרן ושנה לו משה **פירקו** ... נכנסו בניו ושנה להן משה **פירקן** ... וכו'
>
> The Sages taught: What was the order of teaching the Oral Law [in general, not THE Mishnah]? Moses learned directly from the mouth of the Almighty. Aaron entered ...and Moses taught him **his lesson** ... Aaron’s sons entered, and Moses taught them **their lesson** ...

What was that "פרק" - was it a Torah verse, a Mitzvah, a Mishnah?

Comment: Doesn't the question at the beginning of the quotation indicate strongly that the thing under discussion is "_mishna_"? That would mean that your question may be essentially the same as the _b'raisa_'s!

Comment: @WAF Definitely no. Sefaria translates it "What was the order of teaching the Oral Law?" In general, Mihsnah meant "all the oral law"

Comment: In that case, the definition of "_mishna_" (as well, perhaps, as that of "Oral Law") is central to the quotation and to the question. Can you include the assumptions you are making about it in the question? I.e. What are the facts about the _b'raisa_'s discussion that we _do_ already know, upon which an answer to your question should be based? After all, you refer to it at the top as "Torah study", implying certain content, while the _g'mara_ calls it "_mishna_", a term that also appears in the question but for which you are using a different definition.

Comment: @WAF AFAIK the word HaMishnah when referencing to the book of Mishnah as we use it is not used in the Gemmorah. Just as the Posuk "ולימדתם אותם" leads to the general term  "תלמוד תורה", the Pasuk "ושננתם לבנך" leads to the general term משנה תורה meaning תלמוד תורה.

Comment: See https://translate.google.com/#en/iw/lesson - פרק could mean LESSON. _How was the Mishna taught? Moshe would teach ... Aaron the lesson..._

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam in his Introduction to his Pirush Hamishnah starts off with this Gemara and says it means a Mitzvah with all its explanations

From Sefaria

> דע כי כל מצוה שנתן הקב"ה למשה רבינו ע"ה נתנה לו בפירושה. היה אומר לו המצוה ואחר כך אומר לו פירושה וענינה.וכל מה שהוא כולל ספר התורה. וענין למודו לישראל היה כפי שאומר (עירובין פ"ה דף נד:):

> Know that each commandment that the Holy One, blessed be He, gave to Moshe, our teacher – peace be upon him – was given to him with its explanation. He would say to him the commandment and afterward tell him its explanation and content; and [so too with] everything that is included in the Book of the Torah. And the manner of its teaching to Israel is as it is said (Eruvin 54b – in Chapter 5),

> היה משה נכנס באהלו ונכנס אליו בתחלה אהרן ומשה היה אומר לו המצוה הנתונה לו פעם אחת ולימדהו פירושה.

> Moshe would enter his tent, and Aharon would enter it first, and Moshe would tell him the commandment that was given to him, and teach him its explanation one time.

Comment: This fits with the language of the gemara, which implies Moshe was teaching what he had just heard from Hashem.